# Can Entity classes instantiate their own data properties in Kotlin exposed?

Tags: kotlin, orm, foreign-keys, entity, kotlin-exposed

I am starting to learn Kotlin to make a text-based game. I wanted to enforce relational integrity between specific objects (i.e: an instance of `Fuel` cannot be used by more than 1 instance of `Machine`), therefore I decided to try to implement the [Kotlin Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) ORM

I am having a hard time conceptualising the Entity objects however. Here is an example abstract base class `Component`:

```kotlin
package machine.component

// ...imports

abstract class Component(id: EntityID<UUID>, var inputResources: Array<Resource>): UUIDEntity(id) {
    companion object : UUIDEntityClass<Component>(Components)
    val componentName: String by Components.componentName;
    // A map of how many resources are required to build the Component. Maps name of Resource class to quantity required
    abstract val _bluePrint: Map<KClass<out Resource>, Int>
    val resources by Resource optionalReferrersOn Resources.component;

    init {
        val sortedResources = this.resources.groupBy { it::class }
        sortedResources.forEach {
            if (this._bluePrint.keys.contains(it.key)) {
                require(it.value.count() == this._bluePrint[it.key]) {
                    "Component ${this.componentName} needs ${this._bluePrint[it.key]} '${it.key::class.simpleName} resource types to build"
                }
            }
        }
        // TODO: find a way to return the leftover resources to the user
        var leftoverResources: Map<KClass<out Resource>, List<Resource>> = this._resources.filterKeys { !this._bluePrint.keys.contains(it) }
        // Empty input array so it can't be used elsewhere
        inputResources.dropWhile { inputResources.isNotEmpty() }
    }
}
```

The `Resource` entity referred to in `Component` looks like this:

```kotlin
package resource

// ...imports

abstract class Resource (id: EntityID<UUID>): UUIDEntity(id) {
    companion object : UUIDEntityClass<Resource>(Resources)
    abstract val rawName: String;
    protected var hitPoints: Double by Resources.hitPoints;
    override fun toString(): String = "A ${rawName} resource with ${hitPoints} hitpoints"

    // TODO: make this function so that it can only accept an int from fuel being spent, not a random number
    fun extract(hits: Double): Resource? {
        hitPoints -= hits

        if (hitPoints <= 0) {
            return this
        }

        return null
    }
}
```

So, whilst *ignoring* some likely obvious shortcomings with Kotlin basics, the general intention of the Entity class is this:

1. The user instantiates a subtype of this class, passing in a list of (subtype) `Resource` instances
2. The `Component` constructor goes through the `Resource` types, and fails if the quantity of a specific resource does not meet the requirement of the declared `blueprint` property (IIRC `require` should fail the constructor if predicate is false)
3. All leftover resources are returned to the user
4. (**TODO**) The resources required by the blueprint are stored to the `resources` property
5. (**TODO**) The `Component` instance is saved

Step #4 is where I am struggling, is it beyond the scope of an entity to assign itself some data?

If so, do I need to implement some kind of Repository/service wrapper that performs these validation checks and then creates and returns the instance? If a `ComponentRepository` were to exist how can I ensure that `Component` instances can only be created by it.

If the object relationship is flawed in the first place, please feel free to say this